# Java help for modelling a in memory distributed array matrix

Tags: java, matrix, distributed-computing, hazelcast

I want to distribute a huge two dimensional array Object[][]. Mostly holding primitives but also String, Date and Color objects. I want to allow different machines to modify data in this matrix. My problem is that I need some help with the modelling.

As far as I can see there are only distributed maps available like [hazelcalst](http://hazelcast.com/) or [openhft](http://chronicle.software/). But maps are not fitting my needs exactly. So what I can do is store all rows (or all columns) of my array in a map. But when I act on a whole row/column it is blocked for all other threads even if they operate on another index. When I store every "cell" in a distibuted map the row/column index for the map key might me bigger than the whole array itself. Are there better tools or modelling approaches for this scenario? I would need a matrix where I could distribute data and lock just one single cell.

Comment: What do you mean by "the row/column index is bigger than the array"?

Comment: @RealSkeptic a map key of String cell = "1:2" or an array [1,2] as key is probably bigger then the value itself which is just an int. So what I am distributing (potentially over wire) is bigger then two times the value in which I am interested in.